# DialogFragment enter animation not fires on first show

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I set my own animations for dialog window enter but it not fires when I call .show() first time after activity created.

At the gif below you can see that first time animation is drop down and only second time it is slide up that I set.

[image]

**DialogFragment**:

```
public class DateChooseDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public DateChooseDialog() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogFullScreen);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_date_choose, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        params.windowAnimations = R.style.DialogSlideAnimation;
        getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**Animations**:

```
<style name="DialogSlideAnimation" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
</style>

<!-- slide_up -->
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="100%"
    />

<!-- slide_down -->
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="100%"
    />
```

**This is how I show dialog**:

```
DateChooseDialog dateChooseDialog = new DateChooseDialog();
dateChooseDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "date_choose");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is all about keyboard. It resizes your whole window and while keyboard disappears with slide down animation, your whole window resizes it self through sliding down.

Please add this lines to your manifest.

```
<activity (Your current activity)
   ...
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

With these lines, your keyboard will overlay window and it wont resize.
Next challange is detect keyboard is opened to delay animation if neccessary.

Good luck there